# Google Script append Element to HTML Document

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to load data from my Google Script into my HTML Document and send it by email.  When I run the code below, I get the error `ReferenceError: "document" is not defined.`.

I don't understand the cause of the error, or, how to fix it.

My GS Script:

```
function sendEmail(){
  //Email Template
  var emailTemp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("template"); // Access to the HTML document
  // Tab Stichprobe
  var stichprobe = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Stichprobe");
  var stichprobecapital = stichprobe.getRange("A2:L"+stichprobe.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues(); // Array AssetName
  var software = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Software");
  var softwarecapital = software.getRange("A2:E"+software.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues();
  var test=[];
  var stichprobelen = stichprobe.getRange("A2:A"+stichprobe.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues().length; 
  var softwarelen = software.getRange("A2:A"+software.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues().length; 
  var softwareindex = [];

  //Config
  var config = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Config");
  var subject = config.getRange("B1:B1").getValue();
  var counter = config.getRange("B5:B5").getValue();
  var subject = config.getRange("B1:B1").getValue();
  var replyto = config.getRange("B3:B3").getValue();
  var name = config.getRange("B2:B2").getValue();
  var error = config.getRange("B6:B6").getValue();
  var cc = config.getRange("B4:B4").getValue();

  for (var a = 0; a<stichprobelen; a++){
    for (var i = 0; i<softwarelen; i++){
      if (softwarecapital[i][0] == stichprobecapital[a][0]){
        softwareindex.push(i);
      }
    }
    var softindexlen = softwareindex.length;
    for(var b = 0; b < softindexlen; b++) {
      var node =  document.createElement("LI"); 
      var textnode =  document.createTextNode(softwarecapital[0][1]);
      node.appendChild(textnode);
      document.getElementById("liste").appendChild(node); 

    }
    var htmlMessage = emailTemp.evaluate().getContent();
    GmailApp.sendEmail(stichprobecapital[a][2], subject, error,{name:name, htmlBody: htmlMessage, replyTo: replyto, cc: cc});
  }
}
```

My HTML Script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="liste">
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Greetings

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use the HTML DOM Document object in server side code.  The line that is causing the error is:

```
var node =  document.createElement("LI");
```

You can't use HTML DOM objects in Apps Script ".gs" files.  You can use Html Service - Templated HTML with scriptlets:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates

You can't build the HTML for the email in the browser, because you aren't loading a Web App, or sidebar or dialog box.  Even though Apps Script uses JavaScript, it's not exactly the same as what you'd use in the browser.  And the DOM is not JavaScript.  And the DOM is what allows HTML to be manipulated in the browser.

Basically, you need to build the HTML for the list using text concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the [`document` javascript property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) on Apps Script.

It's important to understand that Apps Script doesn't run with a DOM model.

What you want to do is to have a function on your front-end (your HTML file) call the data from the back-end (Apps Script file) and populate the data.

To do this you will user [client-side code](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) and [`withSuccessHandler`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#success_handlers) on your HTML file to populate the lists. This way of doing things complies with the [best-practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices).